# How do I create an RxJS Observable that resolves after .75 seconds?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I would like to create an Observable which resolves after .75 seconds. I tried doing so like this, but the Observable is resolving immediately:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators/delay';
...
refresh(): Observable<any> {
  // Return an observable that resolves after .75 seconds
  return Observable.create().pipe( delay(750) );
}
```

I am using `rxjs` version 5.5.2 and `typescript` version 2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the timer to be the source then you could do the following:

```js
console.log('start');
Rx.Observable.timer(750)
  .subscribe(
    x => console.log('next:', x),
    null,
    () => console.log('complete')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Here are the docs: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer

You have to actually pass something into the create method btw. If you don't I think it throws the following error: `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`

If you want to defer returning some observable then you could do something like this:

```js
console.log('start');
Rx.Observable.create(o => { o.next('test'); o.complete(); })
  .delay(750)
  .subscribe(
    x => console.log('next:', x),
    null,
    () => console.log('complete')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

*Sorry I used old style syntax since I couldn't get the import for the operator to work in the editor.*

Comment: `Observable.create(o => { o.next(); o.complete(); }).pipe( delay(750) );` worked for me